# Using GLTextureView instead of GLSurfaceView in WallpaperService

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, live-wallpaper

I'm trying to create `video wallpaper` using `MediaPlayer`. Also I want to use own shaders to apply visual effects on video. I've figured out that it is possible if use `TextureView`. [Here](https://github.com/izacus/AndroidOpenGLVideoDemo) is an example which works perfect, but for `Activity` only. I need the same functionality for `WallpaperService`. So, I tried to replace  `GLSurfaceView` by [GLTextureView](https://gist.github.com/eleventigers/9545428) class. I had a class which works great:

```
public final class GLWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {

@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    return new WallpaperEngine();
}

private final class WallpaperEngine extends Engine implements
        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    // Slightly modified GLSurfaceView.
    private WallpaperGLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;      
    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
    private EngineCore mRenderer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
        mRenderer = new EngineCore();
        mRenderer.setContext(GLWallpaperService.this);

        mGLSurfaceView = new WallpaperGLSurfaceView(GLWallpaperService.this);
        mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(mRenderer);
        mGLSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
        mGLSurfaceView.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();                      
        mGLSurfaceView.onDestroy();
        mGLSurfaceView = null;          
        mRenderer = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
        super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);

        if (visible) {
            mGLSurfaceView.onResume();
        } else {
            mGLSurfaceView.onPause();
        }           
    }

    /**
     * Lazy as I am, I din't bother using GLWallpaperService (found on
     * GitHub) project for wrapping OpenGL functionality into my wallpaper
     * service. Instead I am using GLSurfaceView and trick it into hooking
     * into Engine provided SurfaceHolder instead of SurfaceView provided
     * one GLSurfaceView extends.
     */
    private final class WallpaperGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
        public WallpaperGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public SurfaceHolder getHolder() {
            return WallpaperEngine.this.getSurfaceHolder();
        }

        /**
         * Should be called once underlying Engine is destroyed. Calling
         * onDetachedFromWindow() will stop rendering thread which is lost
         * otherwise.
         */
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        }
    }

}
}
```

And I got new one by replacing GLSurfaceView on GLTextureView:

```
public final class GLTextureWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {

@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    return new WallpaperEngine();
}

private final class WallpaperEngine extends Engine {

    // Slightly modified GLSurfaceView.
    private WallpaperGLTextureView mGLTextureView;      

    private EngineRenderer mRenderer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
        mRenderer = new EngineRenderer();
        mRenderer.setContext(GLTextureWallpaperService.this);


        mGLTextureView = new WallpaperGLTextureView(GLTextureWallpaperService.this);
        mGLTextureView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mGLTextureView.setRenderer(mRenderer);
        mGLTextureView.setRenderMode(GLTextureView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);        
        mGLTextureView.onPause();           
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();          
        mGLTextureView.onDestroy();
        mGLTextureView = null;          
        mRenderer = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
        super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);

        if (visible) {
            mGLTextureView.onResume();
        } else {
            mGLTextureView.onPause();
        }           
    }

    /**
     * Lazy as I am, I din't bother using GLWallpaperService (found on
     * GitHub) project for wrapping OpenGL functionality into my wallpaper
     * service. Instead I am using GLSurfaceView and trick it into hooking
     * into Engine provided SurfaceHolder instead of SurfaceView provided
     * one GLSurfaceView extends.
     */
    private final class WallpaperGLTextureView extends GLTextureView {
        public WallpaperGLTextureView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        //THIS IS NOT EXIST IN GLTEXTUREVIEW CLASS!!!
        /*
        @Override
        public SurfaceHolder getHolder() {
            Log.e("getHolder", "getHolder");
            return WallpaperEngine.this.getSurfaceHolder();
        }
        */

        //TRIED TO CHANGE getHolder() BY THIS ONE - NO RESULTS!
        @Override
        public SurfaceTexture getSurfaceTexture() {             
            Log.e("getSurfaceTexture", "getSurfaceTexture");
            return (SurfaceTexture) WallpaperEngine.this.getSurfaceHolder();
        }

        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        }
    }               
}
}
```

Renderer class:

```
public class EngineRenderer implements GLTextureView.Renderer {
Context context;

public void setContext(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}


@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {       
    Log.e("ds", "-onSurfaceCreated--");
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {      
    Log.e("ds", "-onSurfaceCreated--");
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    GLES20.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);     
}


@Override
public void onSurfaceDestroyed(GL10 gl) {
}
}
```

I don't get any errors, just black screen. Renderer class is not drawn! It seems to me that `GLTextureView` doesn't have `getHolder()` function.
What should I do? Maybe there is another way to implement my goal.